# HTML files recognized as Django Template in VS Code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I'm new to VS Code, coming from ST3 and TextMate before that. A bit flummoxed why is HTML not autodetected nor is it offered as a choice of language after clicking on the lower-right language indicator?

[image: Screenshot after selecting "Configure File Association for '.html'..."]

I've tried explicitly adding `"files.associations": {"*.html": "html"}` to the User Settings to no effect.

Running VSCode v1.15.1 on macOS v10.12.6.

Comment: Can confirm that there is an "HTML" option in the Language Associations menu in my install: v1.15.1 How odd...

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Include the following line of setting `emmet.includeLanguages": {"django-html": "html"}` in
VSCode's settings.json:

```
{
  "python.jediEnabled": false,
  "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
  "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
  "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
  "editor.minimap.enabled": true,
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Monokai",
  "editor.largeFileOptimizations": false,
  "html.format.indentInnerHtml": true,
  "html.format.indentHandlebars": true,
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "django-html": "html"
  },
  "[django-html]": {

  },
  "files.associations": {
    "*.html": "html"
  }
}
```

It does the fix for me on version 1.33.1

Comment: For more info https://github.com/vscode-django/vscode-django/issues/16 visit here

Comment: **"emmet.includeLanguages": {"django-html": "html"}**

Works for me... TY

Comment: "files.associations": {
    "*.html": "html"
  } works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 28):

**Solved!** I began eliminating extensions and found that Django Template 1.2.0 (`bibhasdn.django-html`) is to blame. As soon as I disabled it, the HTML option returned to the Language Associations menu. Hat tip to @ifconfig for confirming I should expect it to be present.

Comment: If my remark resolved your problem will appreciate you setting it as an answer.

Comment: @Tzvi, It did not but I appreciate your input. As I indicated, I resolved the issue by removing a 3rd party extension.

Comment: was the third party extension - Python Extension Pack that included DJANGO packages as I stated?

Comment: No, I listed the offending extension in the OP: "Django Template 1.2.0 (bibhasdn.django-html"

Comment: Same issue arose with Django Template 1.3. Good to fix it and see the **5**s again.

Answer (score 28):

[image: image for the same]

1) Click on "select language mode" from bottom right toolbar.

2) Select "Configure file association for .html" from the dropdown.

3) Select html from the dropdown.

**This will remove html file being marked as Django-html *every time* you create a html document.**

Comment: Surprisingly, this is working well and I find the answer very useful. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 11):

These settings worked for me in vscode settings.json

```
"files.associations": {
    "**/templates/*.html": "django-html",
    "**/templates/*": "django-txt",
    "**/requirements{/**,*}.{txt,in}": "pip-requirements",
    "*.html": "html"
  },
  "emmet.includeLanguages": { "django-html": "html" }
```

Answer (score 6):

Python Extension Pack that included DJANGO packages made VSCOde see all html as Django Template and set comments as {%comment%} instead of `<!-- -->`

Removing it solved the issue.

Comment: That's not a good solution to remove Python extension when you are a Full Stack developer and use both python and HTML separately...

Answer (score 4):

Just Add this to your Settings.json:

```
"files.associations": {
    "**/templates/*.html": "django-html",
    "**/templates/*": "django-txt",
    "**/requirements{/**,*}.{txt,in}": "pip-requirements",
    "*.html": "html"
  },
  "emmet.includeLanguages": { "django-html": "html" }
```

Open the **Languages(identifier)** menu (`press right Ctl` + `K` then release them and press `M`) and there should be HTML.

[image: Languages(identifier)]

Finally choose `HTML` and restart VSCode.

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest way is to check this. At the right bottom corner of vs code, you can see a footer as below image.

[image: Image of relevant part of VS Code IDE]

So, click the *Django HTML* there. Then a popup with input can be noticed. Enter *HTML* as the input and select *HTML*. Problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

Go to settings.json , and after

```
"files.associations": {
    "**/templates/*.html": "django-html",
    "**/templates/*": "django-txt",
    "**/requirements{/**,*}.{txt,in}": "pip-requirements",
    "*.html": "html"
},
```

put this

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "django-html": "html"
},
```

like this:

```
{
"workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
"editor.fontSize": 15,
"window.zoomLevel": -1,
"files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
"files.associations": {
    "**/templates/*.html": "django-html",
    "**/templates/*": "django-txt",
    "**/requirements{/**,*}.{txt,in}": "pip-requirements",
    "*.html": "html"
},
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "django-html": "html"
},
"[django-html]": {



    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "other": true,
        "comments": true,
        "strings": true
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.

Answer (score 2):

Open your VSCode JSON settings and add these lines

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.html": "html"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To map an extension to a language  in the `settings` search for `association` in the results there should be `Files:Associations`:

[image]

where you can add new `key/value` pairs. where `key` is the extension (Filename Expansion) and `value` is the [language identifier](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers#_known-language-identifiers).

Answer (score 1):

Generally .html and .txt files are recognized as Django Template files by Text-editors.
This can be solved by just adding the given code in VSCode's Setting.json file:

```
"files.associations": {
        "**/templates/*.html": "django-html",
        "**/templates/*": "django-txt",
        "**/requirements{/**,*}.{txt,in}": "pip-requirements",
        "*.html": "html"
      },
```