# Add a formatter (beautifier) to django-html files in Visual Studio Code

Tags: html, django, visual-studio-code, jinja2

I'm using the Django extension for intellisense and syntax highlighting on Jinja templates (VS Code) but cannot figure out how to use my default formatter (HookyQR Beautify) to beautify/format my django-html files. 
Would that be possible?

Answer (score 13):

I need to use beautify only for `django-html` files, I've got prettier working for js, html, css then flake8 and autopep8 for python, for `django-html` prettier wrongly formats jinja template strings,

so I disabled the `django-html` from pettier languages and used these settings got from this [issue discussion.](https://github.com/vscode-django/vscode-django/issues/23), works for me well.

```json
{
    "prettier.disableLanguages": ["django-html"],
    "beautify.language": {
      "html": [
        "django-html"
      ]
    },
    "[django-html]": {
      "editor.formatOnSave": true,
      "editor.defaultFormatter": "HookyQR.beautify"
    }
  }
```

Comment: hi, I have this settings too. but it doesn't format the jinja tags? how sould I fix that?

Comment: Did you set the html inside the template folders as "django-html", if not  add it using [this settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63425265/12167598), still not formatting, check if beautify is properly installed, and all the above settings are highlighted in VS code(ie all of them are shown valid)..also I'm using windows.. package names can be different for mac or linux.

Comment: yes, I have django-html and beautify and the settings too. but it just will format the html tags. and nothing for jinja. I have to stack-questions related to this but still no one have a solution.

Comment: ```
  "indentationRules": {
    "increaseIndentPattern": "((\\<)(body|address|blockquote|dd|div|dl|dt|tr|tbody|thead|fieldset|form|frame|frameset|h1|h2|h3||q|s|samp|script|select|small|span|strike|strong|style|sub|sup|table|tbody|td|textarea|tfoot|th|thead|title|tr|tt|u|var))|(\\{\\%)\\s*(|ifnotequal|from|low|regroup|ssi|spaceless|templatetag|widthratio|with|verbatim|thumbnail)",
    "decreaseIndentPattern": "((\\<\\/)(.*)*(\\>))|((\\{\\%)\\s*(empty|elif|else|end(ifequal|ifnotequal|spaceless|with|verbatim|thumbnail)))"
  }
}
```
this is some of rules needed for indention.

Comment: With my little knowledge, there is no formatter that can target jinja directly, beautify also ignores it, and only corrects the general indentation and other html, for the updates I think there is an open issue and discussion running on the prettier github repo regarding this.. In a nutshell they are saying, there is not a standardized way how jinja can be written or cop up with everyone's coding styles... and I'm not that experienced either to say an opinion regarding this, I use it because it does the html part correct while the prettier joins them mostly in a single line.

Comment: thanks for attention. I hope someone could create that ext.

Comment: but actually I have built the syntax indentation, just it's not auto-format on save/paste.

Comment: Oh, that sounds great, so if you can get that to a vs code extension, then it will be very good for everyone , I don't actually know how that works, but with VS code's backends communication the save/paste formatting can be implemented, and that is not necessary too.. you can implement select&format and a timer based formatting as a first step and can build up a package.

Comment: In theory. But I don't have enough skills to create an extension for vscode. And even the documentation is not suitable for beginners. The only thing I could do was to provide that regex.

Comment: with some effort, you can make a pull request to add that feature with codes to beautify or prettier teams, or aleast throw this matter, in the issue discussion I said earlier.. I'm also not that much a skilled to help, but assuming a JS and API handling knowledge(vs code is in top of js and react),..can do it..and Brad Traversy got a video too if you need a start..  regex in JS similar to python, anyway how you are doing that formatting now t.. is with opening the file and running by line through the script.

Comment: Here is what I get with that command: This feature is no longer supported. Instead, configure VS Code [default formatters](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode#default-formatter) or use .prettierignore.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to have sorted it for me, allowing me to keep HookyQR Beautify for normal HTML files and have a separate one for django-html files:

```
"beautify.language": {
    "html": [
        "django-html"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HookyQR Beautify is deprecated according to VS Code. You can find an up to date solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77164118/12199445