# how can I format django-html code in vscode

Tags: html, django, visual-studio-code, formatting

So, recently I have been coding in Django and in its templates folder, as we know, we put HTML files. So earlier when I use to code in HTML only(not Django-HTML), vscode used to auto-format the code and align the tags with tab spaces properly. but in Django-html, the code is not getting auto formatted, also I have enabled the 'prettier extension' but still this problem exists:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block title %}Contact Us {% endblock title %} {%
block contactactive %} active{% endblock contactactive %} {% block body %}
  <div class="container my-4">
  <h2>Contact our developers!</h2>
  <form action="/contact/" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input
   type="text"
   class="form-control"
   id="name"
   name="name"
   placeholder="enter your full name"
   />
   </div>
   </div>

{% block body %}
```

but I want my code to be formatted like this:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} 
{% block title %}Contact Us {% endblock title %} 
{%block contactactive %} active{% endblock contactactive %} 

{% block body %}
<div class="container my-4">
  <h2>Contact our developers!</h2>
  <form action="/contact/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        id="name"
        name="name"
        placeholder="enter your full name"
      />
    </div>
</div>
{% block body %}
```

are there any settings or any tools which I should enable to solve this problem?

Comment: I had also encountered same. you can try this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61224622/12846255)